# Why does Moment.js return the next day when timezone is given?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a time and timezone, say 11:00pm in America/Los_Angeles. I want to create a Moment.js object from that time (using `moment-timezone` to work with timezones).

This works as expected, printing 11pm with today's date, however it's in my local timezone.

```
moment('11:00pm', 'h:mma').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

To make sure the timezone is set correctly I tried the following, however this prints 11pm with tomorrow's date.

```
moment.tz('11:00pm', 'h:mma', "America/Los_Angeles").format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j723oceL/

Why does it print tomorrow's date when a timezone is used?

Comment: FWIW, works fine for me…

Comment: Now that it's past midnight local time for me it works fine for me also. This issue seems to just occur for me in the afternoon I guess. I'm on Pacific time.